# Color of potassium permanganate and potassium dichromate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals

In $\ce{KMnO4}$, the Oxidation state of $\ce{Mn}$ is +7, which results in an electronic configuration as $\ce{[Ar] 4s^0 3d^0}$

In $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$,the Oxidation state of $\ce{Cr}$ is +6, which results in an electronic configuration as $\ce{[Ar] 4s^0 3d^0}$

As it is clearly visible there are no $\ce{d}$ electrons in either of these compounds but still, they are coloured.

My Doubt:

1. If there's no $\ce{d-d}$ transition in these compounds what gives these compounds their colour?
2. Are there other transition element compounds whose colour is not because of $\ce{d-d}$ transition?

Comment: See [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://home.iitk.ac.in/~madhavr/CHM102/Notes_on_Color_of_Inorganic_Complexes.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjsmbyz1dfZAhWoVt8KHRalDeUQFjAGegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw0oLHQWvogzhUBNFkob8p6O).